# Very very slow debugging in ASP.NET 4 for Visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

when i debug my asp.net web-application it is very slow on my machine when i debug.

are their any way to make this fast like in MVC we exclude the file if not want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is rather vague. What exactly is slow about it? The application execution, the time it takes to launch the application?

If the application takes a long time to start, one thing you might want to try is to go to the **Debug** menu and choose **Delete All Breakpoints**. Breakpoints don't make slower under normal conditions, but as you change your code, some breakpoint locations may become invalid. Having those arround can slow it down *a lot*. So clear all the breakpoints and only set the ones you need.

Comment: This worked for me, even though I had no breakpoints set. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost or alter C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

To

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
#::1             localhost
```